# OSGi module causes runtime error when running it from Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, osgi, netbeans-7, rcp

We are developing a Netbeans RCP application that includes NB modules, and OSGi modules. When running the developed RCP application, it gives a NoSuchMethodFoundException on ServiceTracker(ServiceTrackerCustomizer) constructor.

It is weird that when this application is packed as a .Zip distribution and extracted & executed from the .Zip package it works. Also, this application runs quite well on some machines(that have the same version and configuration) and it will give the same error on other machines.

Is there any solution for this? Did we make a mistake in RCP and OSGi config, or is this an Netbeans installation problem?

I have been inspecting this issue for a long time, and I haven't been able to find a solution for it.

Configuration:

Windows 8 x64
Netbeans 7.3 or 7.3.1 ( any of both versions )

Thanks...

Comment: Which method name?? It's kind of important to state this if you're reporting a NoSuchMethodError... ;-)

Comment: Your update doesn't make sense. `ServiceTrackerCustomizer` doesn't have a constructor, it's an interface. How about posting the actual stack trace?

Comment: You are right, updated again, i am not able to provide any stack trace, due to security issues. I wish i could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An additional constructor was added to `ServiceTracker` in release 4.3 (the one which takes a `java.lang.Class` as its second argument). It's likely that you developed the bundle against a higher version of OSGi than is supported by NetBeans.

Normally this kind of error can be avoided with proper versioning. Your bundle should import the org.osgi.util.tracker package with version range `[1.5,2.0)` as follows:

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.util.tracker; version="[1.5,2.0)"
```

If NetBeans does not support OSGi R4.3 (I'm not aware myself whether it does or not) then you should develop against R4.2 and avoid the additional methods which were added in 4.3.

Comment: Your answers seems relevant but strange thing is that, it does not work when running RCP App from IDE but It runs when it is packed as a .Zip distribution.

Comment: There are many, many reasons why there could be a difference in the configuration of the runtime between launching from the IDE versus launching an exported zip. For example if you are able to get the OSGi Gogo shell working then take a look at bundle 0, which represents the core OSGi framework bundle, and see whether it's a different version.

Comment: Thanks your guidance on running OSGi version helped a lot. You were right, just Netbeans tries  to use 4.2 runtime but it allows to develop on 5.0.0 core library

Comment: But how can we change automatically added 4.2 compendium to 4.3, it says that netbeans support cmpn 4.3?

Comment: I don't know enough about NetBeans to answer the last question, sorry.